# Heroku app doesn't have any CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I just uploaded my site to heroku but none of the styles are showing. I have no idea what the problem is.

Heroku site http://shielded-garden-1674.herokuapp.com/

This is my Github repo https://github.com/LaurentLousky/todolist

This is what "heroku log" gives me. http://pastebin.com/cj17Pc4a

Im using Foundation 5 for styling.

Thank you all so much, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Heroku will not serve your assets. You should add this to `config/application.rb`:

`config.serve_static_assets = true`

Or add this to the `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` :

`gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#serve-assets and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline for a more thorough explanation

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to see your Heroku app.

However, check if your code adds/links your css files in the same way your files are named. For example if in your code your files are named "Styles.css", make sure your code states the name of your files as "Styles.css" and not "styles.css" because once in Heroku cloud, system may not recognize the file.